# Php RegExp, acpets only letters and numbers and dot in specific range and dot character should not use for start and end

Tags: php, regex

I was just reading about regexp and It's really hard to figure out.
Just a little help I need.
I want to check username for registration on my website, It should have this conditions:

minimum chars = 4

maximum chars = 32

accepts lowercase letters

accepts uppercase letters

accepts dot `.` (not in first position and last character position)
and the dot `.` character can not be came after another `.`

I did try this:
`^[\a.a-zA-Z]` but it's not working.
Could someone help me on that?

Comment: sorry I've forgot some cases, I've edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following approach with `preg_match`,`strpos` functions and specific regex pattern:

```
function validateUsername($username = '') {
    return (strpos($username, "..") === false) 
           && preg_match('/^(?!\.)[a-z.]{3,31}[^.]$/i', $username);
}

// Testing ...
var_dump(validateUsername('some.UserName.with.dotS'));   // bool(true)
var_dump(validateUsername('some.UserName..with.dotS'));  // bool(false)
var_dump(validateUsername('.someusernamE'));             // bool(false)
var_dump(validateUsername('abc.'));                      // bool(false)
```

Comment: what if there where 3 dots ?

Comment: @Omid, 3 or 4 or more dots: it would consider it as invalid. Check this `'some.UserName.....dotS'` input